# Node-Red save to local file

Tags: javascript, html, node-red

have looked serveral days now to find a Possibility to save data from my MySQL Database to a local file (on the client PC not the server) to analyze the Data there. 
I have tried the standard file out node but that only saves to the server File system.

the Flow i am currently using is like this:

[image: current flow]

If the Button is clicked the data collected by the Function node is send to the Template node.

The last approach i have found some minutes ago was this: [Data URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3665147/9087531), but I dont get how to put my msg.payload to the file content.
Sorry for this dumb questions but im barely new to HTML and using it in node-red.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to build a JS app or are only want to create backups of some database on your local machine? Please clarify your goals and ask questions with only one topic per question. For example: most MySQL databases are not accessibly from outside a hosting-companies network for security reasons. That might be a reason, why you can dump a backup on the server, but not on you local machine. Please check your connection. If the question on the other hand is about how to display a line break in a UI dialog, please remove any other parts from the question…

Comment: The reason for doing this is to get an easy way to analyze the data on a local machine.
I asked for both ways because I would prefer the download one over the copy paste approach but it would be ok if one way doesn't work

Comment: If you just want to browse a database or do some example queries for non-regular statistic evaluations you can use a UI tool like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), which may also connect to the server via SSH and thus avoid the limitation of most MySQL databases not being accessible from another network. Please refer to their documentation too.

Comment: Yeah for me it would be an easy way to use Workbench, but I have to publish all that to people with no afford of learning MySQL wich can only load the data with their tools, that ist my big problem. With node-red they could click through my mask and get the right data on the computer. The constrain with one user per time is the only downside then.

Comment: Edit the question to show us what you have already tried, then we may be able to help you fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `http-in` and `http-out` nodes to create a HTTP endpoint that will return the data you want.

If you wire the output from the `http-in` to the input of the `database` node then the output from the `function` node to the input on the `http-out`.

You can then just point your browser at the URL you configure in the `http-in` node and the browser should download the data so you can save it locally. You may need to set the Content-Type header to make sure the browser does the right thing with the data.